# C# - How to set a variable on task completion

Tags: c#, timer, task

I have a timer class that runs a while loop for a fixed amount of time. I want to run that class in a seprate thread then return a variable once it is finished. Basically, I want to set "emailTimerExpired" to `true` once the timer finishes. It looks like the continuewith statment is never called. Does this have something to do with how I am setting up the task?

```
Task timerTask = new Task(() => emailTimer.StartTimer(cancelToken,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(emailTimeSpan)));
timerTask.ContinueWith(task => { emailTimerExpired = true; });
timerTask.Start();
```

Comment: are you using breakpoints to determine whether or not `ContinueWith` is actually called?

Comment: Have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait(v=vs.110).aspx ? This looks like it can help you?

Comment: Using tasks to measure time is something of an anti-pattern. Have you looked into the [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. How are you checking the `emailTimerExpired` variable? Maybe you have a race condition, or maybe you are somehow checking the wrong instance's variable. Note that an exception or the original task's cancel token being set will cause the `ContinueWith` task to run which probably breaks some assumptions you have.

Comment: It's impossible to adequately comprehend the question without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem and otherwise shows what you are doing. What little is here includes a number of red flags. For instance: _"runs a while loop for a fixed amount of time"_ -- a loop that exists solely for the purpose of looping for some period of time is a _horrible_ implementation choice. .NET includes a number of vastly superior mechanisms for timing things. It sounds like you're entire approach is just broken; you will do better seeking advice for the broader problem, not this specific one.